# Is it a bug in ReduceVocab() or missing something?

Tags: c, word2vec

here's a piece of code of `word2vec` i've downloaded from [google word2vec.c](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/source/default/source):

```
// Reduces the vocabulary by removing infrequent tokens
void ReduceVocab() {
    int a, b = 0;
    unsigned int hash;
    for (a = 0; a < vocab_size; a++) if (vocab[a].cn > min_reduce) {
            vocab[b].cn = vocab[a].cn;
            vocab[b].word = vocab[a].word;
            b++;
        } else free(vocab[a].word);
    vocab_size = b;
    
    for (a = 0; a < vocab_hash_size; a++) vocab_hash[a] = -1;
    for (a = 0; a < vocab_size; a++) {
        // Hash will be re-computed, as it is not actual
        hash = GetWordHash(vocab[a].word);
        while (vocab_hash[hash] != -1) hash = (hash + 1) % vocab_hash_size;
        vocab_hash[hash] = a;
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    min_reduce++;
}
```

which is called in `LearnVocabFromTrainFile` function.
Assume `min_reduce=5`
So if the input file is not that good, I mean if a word say "hello" that appeared `4` times when `ReduceVocab` called, and the `vocab` will remove `hello` from itself.

Later, when `ReduceVocab` called again and luckly `hello` appeared `5` times.. and it seems `ReduceVocab` will remove `hello` again.

As in truth, `hello` appeared 9 times which should be in the `vocab`, but the code above removed it.
it takes not such matter as it seems the situation happens seldomly. Just wondering my analysis is right or i've missed something in the code.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Variable declarations are important. Please post a complete example with all declarations present and some sort of context where the function is used. See [mcve]

Comment: thanks, i've added the url where i download the code.

Answer (score 1):

A better URL for reviewing the relevant source is:

https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec/blob/master/word2vec.c#L185

As I understand it, this is not a bug – just a compromise with non-intuitive effects.

This code uses an intentionally rough/approximate method of ensuring the number of tracked vocabulary terms never exceeds `0.7 * vocab_hash_size` (21 million). Whenever the number of terms hits that high-water mark, all terms with fewer than `min_reduce` occurrences are discarded - & `min_reduce` is increased to take even more, next time.

(And in practice, this escalating-floor, along with the typical long-tail Zipfian distribution of word frequences, can mean that at each triggered `ReduceVocab` operation, *most* terms are discarded, bringing the total vocab size to something that's way smaller than `0.7 * vocab_hash_size`.)

An unavoidable effect of discarding known counts, in an interim running fashion, is that counts after each discard are no longer complete & exact. The relative position of terms in the corpus can thus have a big effect on which terms are `ReduceVocab`-pruned - with terms that "just miss" the cutoff each time potentially having far more occurrences, in total, than the final `min_reduce`. And further, all final counts of less-frequent words might be incomplete, if the term's early occurrence counts didn't survive earlier `ReduceVocab` steps.

Still, this approach works to keep the vocabulary-survey from taking an arbitrary amount of RAM, and the imprecision in the tail of rarer word counts isn't too big of a concern in typical cases.

If you have the RAM & want to prevent this behavior, you could edit the source to make `vocab_hash_size` arbitrarily larger, so that either `ReduceVocab()` is never triggered (and thus your final counts are exact), or happens rarely enough that any words it affects don't concern you.

Comment: tks for your answer, especially with `long-tail Zipfian distribution` info.  It's rarely happen in reality. and `zipf distribution` do help me to understand why it is rarely happen.